# How to determine which System Image goes with which system?

Tags: windows-7, windows, restore, windows-backup, windows-7-backup

I created system images using Windows Backup and Restore for multiple computers using Windows 7.  The System Image folders were named according to the System Name available within Windows.

Since the creation of those System Images, several users have changed the System Name of their systems within Windows.  Now I have no idea which System Images go with which system.

Is there any way to tell which System Image went with which system once the System Names have been changed? Perhaps GUIDs that would be unique to each system?

Comment: It sounds like your backups are out of date, so why not create new backups?

Comment: Good question.  The images are from when the systems were set up with specific configurations, and I want to have backups if the systems need to be restored to those configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you mount your VHD files and retrieve your registry file - particularly HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software, which is located in C:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE

Mount VHD file:

1. start->run -  compmgmt.msc
2. click Disk Management and wait for it to mount the drives
3. right-click Disk Management, select attach VHD file.

Then make a copy of the VHD's Software Hive(registry file) -`<Drive>:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE`

View MachineGuid:

1. Open Regedit, and click File->Load the registry hive.
2. Search for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\ and select MachineGuid.
3. Match against running computers'  OS MachineGuid.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877(v=vs.85).aspx